# ClassNotFound exception in quarkus dev mode when reading a message from RabbitMq using camel

Tags: apache-camel, quarkus

I'm using apache-camel-quarkus to read from a RabbitMq queue and everything works fine in production. But when I run it in dev mode and try to perform a use-case where the RabbitMq is used, I'm getting an exception while deserializing the message from the queue

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: messaging.model.ReportAvailableMessage
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:429)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:405)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:756)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1995)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1862)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:493)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:451)
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQMessageConverter.deserializeBody(RabbitMQMessageConverter.java:354)
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQMessageConverter.populateMessageBody(RabbitMQMessageConverter.java:344)
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQMessageConverter.populateRabbitExchange(RabbitMQMessageConverter.java:289)
```

It's somewhat related to the classpath in dev mode.
The same happened for integration tests and I had to use this property to fix it

```
quarkus.test.flat-class-path=true
```

I did some search and tried to use `quarkus.class-loading.parent-first-artifacts` with the artifact id of my app but it didn't work either.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?
Thanks

Env:
Quarkus version: 2.4.0.Final, Camel: 2.2.0

Comment: Quarkus documentation states that 
"Changes tests to use the 'flat' ClassPath used in Quarkus 1.x versions. This means all Quarkus and test classes are loaded in the same ClassLoader, however it means you cannot use continuous testing. Note that if you find this necessary for your application then you may also have problems running in development mode, which cannot use a flat class path."

So it may be that you cannot use dev mode at all, if you require this parameter to be true.

Comment: @StefanR using this flag in tests is a workaround to be able to deploy the app in production after running the integration tests. But this shouldn't be necessary since it works fine in production. That's why I posted this question since it seems that something is not compatible with dev mode or tests when using rabbitMQ consumer from camel-quarkus